# Android layout align and fill remaining space in view

Tags: android, layout, android-layout, android-linearlayout

For my application I make a screen where you can see information about the shop. This is what I'v got now.(in the image below) The remaining area I'd like to fill with an image or google maps view. Is it possible to just fill the remaining area via xml? Or how do I tackle this problem?

Second question is:
As you can see in the white area the icons or nice centred. I want to align the icons on the block above it with the left side of the icons in the white box. How do i do this?

Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >    

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/winkels_uren_bg"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
    android:paddingLeft="35dp">
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/lblStraat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/map"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"

        />
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/telefoonnr"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/telefoon_icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        />
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <LinearLayout 
        style="@style/winkelinfoicons">
        <ImageButton
            style="@style/winkelinfoicon"
            android:id="@+id/icobancontact"
            android:background="@null" 
            />

        <ImageButton
             style="@style/winkelinfoicon"
            android:id="@+id/icomarkt"
            android:background="@null"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        style="@style/winkelinfoicons">
        <ImageButton
            style="@style/winkelinfoicon" 
            android:id="@+id/icoeducatie"
            android:background="@null"
            />
        <ImageButton
            style="@style/winkelinfoicon" 
            android:id="@+id/icomobielestand"
            android:background="@null"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        style="@style/winkelinfoicons">
        <ImageButton
            style="@style/winkelinfoicon" 
            android:id="@+id/icogeschenken"
            android:background="@null"
            />
        <ImageButton
            style="@style/winkelinfoicon" 
            android:id="@+id/icovoeding"
            android:background="@null"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        style="@style/winkelinfoicons">
        <ImageButton
            style="@style/winkelinfoicon" 
            android:id="@+id/icoklasbezoek"
            android:background="@null"
            />
        <ImageButton
            style="@style/winkelinfoicon" 
            android:id="@+id/icowinkel"
            android:background="@null"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Actually I work with include but I now pasted the complete xml here :).

[image: Design image]

Comment: I want to target multiple screensizes. And I'm always afraid that it won't be the same on the diffrent screens. Or won't there be a problem?

Comment: there only be a problem if you hardcode the layout file.

Comment: Now I turned it into a Relative layout. But I still can't get the Icons with phone and map exactly ligned out to the euro sign en market place icon. Because I want that gradient background I need to place them in a Layout. Any solution is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a similar problem to the alignment problem. Here's how I fixed it. I calculated the width in dp of the icons down. I centered it. I set the width of the textviews above to the same width of the calculated value and centered it also.

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout supports assigning a weight to individual children which will help you to occupy the space. This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view, and allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view. Default weight is 0

calculation to assign any remaining space between child

space assign to child = (child individual weight) / (sum of weight of every child in Linear Layout)

Example: if there are three text boxes and two of them declare a weight of 1, while the third one is given no weight (0), then remaining space assign to
1st text box = 1/(1+1+0) 2nd text box = 1/(1+1+0) 3rd text box = 0/(1+1+0)

Just try this xml which i used weight to occupy the  remaining space

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/layout" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_margin="1dip" android:orientation="horizontal">
      <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight=".7" android:orientation="vertical">
         <Button android:id="@+id/header" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/header" android:text="header" />
         <TextView android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="4" android:layout_height="275dp" android:text="this is  the   memo/reciept part \r\n this is  the   memo/reciept part " />
         <EditText android:id="@+id/editText2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_span="3" android:padding="18dip" android:text="edit text" android:textColor="#000" android:textSize="18sp" />
         <Button android:id="@+id/footer" android:background="@drawable/cashierinputtext" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:textSize="18sp" android:text="footer" android:padding="18dip" android:textColor="#000" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_margin="0.5dip" android:layout_weight="1.9" android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_vertical" android:orientation="vertical">
         <Button android:id="@+id/F1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="4dip" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:background="@drawable/entrykeybutton" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="f1" />
         <Button android:id="@+id/F2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="4dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:background="@drawable/entrykeybutton" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="f2" />
         <Button android:id="@+id/F3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="4dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/entrykeybutton" android:text="f3" />
         <Button android:id="@+id/F4" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="4dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:background="@drawable/entrykeybutton" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="f4" />
         <Button android:id="@+id/F5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="4dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/entrykeybutton" android:text="f5" />
         <Button android:id="@+id/F6" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="4dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:background="@drawable/entrykeybutton" android:text="f6" />
         <Button android:id="@+id/F7" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="4dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:background="@drawable/entrykeybutton" android:text="f7" />
         <Button android:id="@+id/F8" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="4dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:background="@drawable/entrykeybutton" android:text="f8" />
      </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```